# Using ( and ) inside a replacement pattern to apply an operator on a sub pattern

Tags: regex, parentheses

In regular expressions one can use parenthesis to change what is affected by an operator. For exemple, if i want a pattern to be optional, i can do :

```
bla bla bla (foo_.*_)? bla bla bla
```

Here i need to use the parenthesis to apply operator `?` on `foo_.*_` and not just on the last `_`.

Now what if i want to do the same thing, but in a replacement pattern, where parenthesis are used to define the groups ? If i escape the parenthesis it will represent the character `(`, and if i don't it will represent the symbol to create a group. What if i want to use it as described above ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here :

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html

I needed to add `?:` to create a "non-capturing" group.